# PHP/MySQL - Using results of a query to use in another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, fetch

I have two tables, one with posts and another one with comments:

```
posts
-----
ID
user_ID
text
date

comments
--------
ID
post_ID
user_ID
text
date
```

I want to display every post and for each post, I want to display the related comments. So I made two queries:

```
include('bdd.php');
$reponse = $bdd->query('
    SELECT posts.ID AS post_ID, posts.user_ID, posts.text, posts.date FROM posts
    ORDER BY posts.ID DESC
');
while ($post = $reponse->fetch()){
    //displaying a post
    $get_comments=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_ID ='.$post['post_ID']);
    while($comment = $get_comments->fecth()){
         //displaying a comment
         echo $comment['text']
    }
}
```

But the code stops and only displays the first post without the comments.

Comment: are you using PDO?   Try to insert `$reponse->execute();` before first while. OR replace `$bdd->prepare();` with `$bdd->query();`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot it when I simplified the code, I just added it. It doesn't solve the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i am posting it as answer, accept it. happy coding

Comment: No, don't. It doesn't solve the problem, it still doesn't work. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: make sure the post your displaying must have some comments on your database.Test your mysql query and loop. your code is ok. use `echo $bdd->rowCount();` to check numbers of rows selected

Comment: `$get_comments->fecth()` check your `fetch()` spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to insert

```
 $reponse->execute();
```

before first `while`. OR replace 
`$bdd->prepare();` with `$bdd->query();`

Typo error:

`$get_comments->fecth()` check your `fetch()` spelling

Comment: It was the spelling mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

is the select query even correct??

```
SELECT posts.ID AS post_ID, posts.user_ID, posts.text, posts.date
ORDER BY posts.ID DESC
```

It has no FROM clause. Should have been as below:

```
SELECT posts.ID AS post_ID, posts.user_ID, posts.text, posts.date FROM posts
ORDER BY posts.ID DESC
```

Comment: You're right, infact, I simplified the code, and I forgot the FROM. But that's not the problem. Thanks anyway. I added the FROM.